# WooCommerce: Retrieve the name of the subcategory of a product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to retrieve the name of the subcategory of a product.

How would I get the last child category?

Thanks in advance!

I know that the following code retrieves all categories but it outputs it in an alphabetical order and not in a parent > child order.

`<?php $product->get_categories();?>`

Answer (score 0):

to get the sub categories list and the categories query the parent and child like below

```
$taxonomyName = "product_cat";
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));

foreach ($parent_terms as $parent) {
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $parent->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->name, $taxonomyName) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
}
```